# Asignar un string de un array a un char**

Tags: array, c

tengo un problema con este método. Recibe un array de personas, y encuentra en el array las personas cuya inicial del nombre coincida con la letra recibida como parámetro y devuelve el conjunto de los nombres de estas personas. No funciona, si compila pero no devuelve nada. Gracias.

```
char** listadoNombres(Persona *ap, int tamanyo, char letra)
{
    char **listado;
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanyo; i++)
    {
        if (ap[i].nombre[0] == letra)
        {
            memcpy(listado[i], &(*ap[i].nombre), sizeof(ap[i].nombre));
        }
    }
    return listado;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un puntero solo almacena una dirección de memoria. Pero te permite escribir y leer en ella.

`listado` no está apuntando a ninguna parte.

Para arreglarlo puedes asignarle memoria del heap que luego debes borrar cuando no uses más:

```
char** listado = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * tamanyo);
```

Con esto ya podrás guardar en memoria las direcciones de los strings que cumplen la condición:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tamanyo; i++)
{
    if (ap[i].nombre[0] == letra)
    {
        listado[i] = ap[i]->nombre;
    }
    else
    {
        // Si no cumple la condición, se establece en NULL porque
        // la memoria debe ser inicializada y cuando leas el
        // arreglo las posiciones sin valor apuntarán todas a NULL
        listado[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

No das más detalles, pero puedes adaptarlo a tus necesidades. Si quisieras que el arreglo tenga una copia de los nombres, tendrías que asignar más memoria del heap y ahí si te sería útil `memcpy`.